# How to set a transparent background to a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

How to set a transparent background to a `DataGrid`?

The following did not work:

```
<DataGrid  Background="Transparent"  >
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

It stays white as snow with this code :)

**EDIT:**

updated the code (copy paste issue)

Comment: This is not the code you are using (look at the 'false' in the first line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the [`RowBackground`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowbackground(v=vs.110).aspx) also to `Transparent`:

```
<DataGrid Background="Transparent" RowBackground="Transparent">
```

Comment: Still not looking how you'd expect? Don't forget you can set 
`HeadersVisibility="None"`